# What code is being used here for use with fonts and glyphs?

Tags: javascript, fonts, svg, glyph

I was looking through some of the files used in Vexflow and I'm trying to add new glyphs for the score however, I don't know what code is being used here in the vex.flow.font.js file:

```
Vex.Flow.Font = {"glyphs":{"vb":{"x_min":0,"x_max":428.75,"ha":438,"o":"m 262 186 b 273 186 266 186 272 186 b 274 186 273 186 274 186 b 285 186 274 186 280 186 b 428 48 375 181 428 122 b 386 -68 428 12 416 -29 b 155 -187 329 -145 236 -187 b 12 -111 92 -187 38 -162 b 0 -51 4 -91 0 -72 b 262 186 0 58 122 179 "}
```

To my understanding, the code above is referenced by another file (glyph.js) to render an svg. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Vex.Flow.Font = {"glyphs": {
    "vb": {
        "x_min": 0,
        "x_max": 428.75,
        "ha": 438,
        "o": "m 262 186 b 273 186 266 186 272 186 b 274 186 273 186 274 186 b 285 186 274 186 280 186 b 428 48 375 181 428 122 b 386 -68 428 12 416 -29 b 155 -187 329 -145 236 -187 b 12 -111 92 -187 38 -162 b 0 -51 4 -91 0 -72 b 262 186 0 58 122 179 "}}}
```

`glyphs` is a list of glyphs, mapping them from their code to their info. So `vb` is a glyph code, and the map with four values is its description. `x_min` and `x_max` describe horizontal metrics. `x_min` set to zero means start drawing the glyph at the current cursor point, and the value of `x_max` specifies cursor's movement to the right. I have no idea what is `ha` and what does it do. `o` is the outline of the glyphs to be rendered. It is described in a format similar to [SVG paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html). For the start, `m 262 186` means move to pixel (262, 186), `b 273...` means draw a bezier curve with these points, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your Help Mosafa :) Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: According to usage in `three.js`, it looks like it applies `ha` to `offsetX`, so it's another horizontal spacing indicator